# Block's bounding box's glitching strange way

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have something kind of

```
private AxisAlignedBB boundingBox = new AxisAlignedBB(-0.34D, 0D, -0.34D, 1.34D, 3.24D, 1.34D);

@Override
public AxisAlignedBB getCollisionBoundingBox(IBlockState blockState, World worldIn, BlockPos pos)
{
    return boundingBox;
}

@Override
public AxisAlignedBB getSelectedBoundingBox(IBlockState state, World worldIn, BlockPos pos)
{
    return boundingBox.offset(pos);
}

@Override
public boolean isFullCube(IBlockState state) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isOpaqueCube(IBlockState state) {
    return false;
}
```

in the class of my tile entity. And when i'm trying to walk through the middle of block, the collision bounding box works correct, but when i try to jump on the block, i get stuck in it, trying to fall through. Also i get stuck in the same block if i try to walk into the block from the corners or trying to stand on the whole construction: i fall until i reach the height of 2D and then glitches begin. Corners of the block act as if there was no bounding box for the corners. Is it possible to make block bounding boxes work correct?

[The block and its bounding box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2kph.jpg)

[Actual working (or partially working) area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfvKf.jpg)

Comment: Minecraft's bounding box code isn't quite designed for hitboxes that go outside of the normal bounds.  It can be done for collision, but not for selection.  Take a look at `BlockFence` for an example.  (I'm working on a more complete answer right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using dummy blocks for this. When your block is placed, spawn dummy blocks in the required areas. When your block, or the dummy blocks, are broken, break the entire structure of dummies and true blocks.